# Newsletter preview box doesn't disappear

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I went to *stackoverflow.com/users/edit/my_SO_id* page and clicked on "See an example newsletter" link. The box with an example newsletter appeared:

[image]

Then I clicked on the dark zone:

[image]

The dark overlay vanished, but the box did not. I tried pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> and the outcome was the same (no surprises here).

(I believe) The bug is reproducible on all SE sites.

Comment: Yup, only the "X" works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This popup still used some custom popup javascript. Most of the popups were standardized to support layering (like in the suggested edit -> improve/reject+edit case), this one somehow slipped through.

A fix is rolling out in the next build (rev `2015.2.19.3097` on meta, `2015.2.19.2316` on sites).